# Insert empty rows in between fields or move entries

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of items in column A (starting from A12) I want to know the best way to do this. I want there to be a 7 row gap between all the entries. These entries will have additions so some code that perhaps says if text here then add 7 rows below until no more. Or is there a way to code it so it just pushes the entries into different fields (7+ down). What would the code look like?

Basic adding row is:

```
Range("A13").EntireRow.Insert
```

Comment: Your safest bet is probably to start at finding the last row, then loop through your range from bottom to top inserting 7 rows each iteration, will automatically stop when reaching the top.

Comment: @Plutian How would I go about doing this? code wise? The worksheet is called "Data"

Comment: Patience is a virtue! I've posted my answer, all you have to do is adjust the sheet and column if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub numberf()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do While lastrow > 2
    Range("A" & lastrow).EntireRow.Resize(7).Insert
    lastrow = lastrow - 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As I suggested, a reverse loop that does the trick. Props to @MilesFett with the resize option, as my first idea was to loop 7 times inserting a row. This is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

So, along with @Plutian and his code to insert new rows, I edited this to `filldown` the new rows with data from each cell that is not blank. Hope this helps.

```
Sub numberf()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Do While lastrow > 12
        Range("A" & lastrow).EntireRow.Resize(7).Insert
        lastrow = lastrow - 1
        Debug.Print lastrow
    Loop

    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1
    For i = 12 To lastrow Step 8
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Range("A" & i).Resize(8).EntireRow.FillDown
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a bit too simple, it should iterate through all entries and its for a specific worksheet called "Data"

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've used this answer to improve mine. +1 for suggesting the resize method.

Comment: @Donald I edited the code to include Plutian's code and added a `For Next` in order to fill or push the entries into the newly created rows. Hope it helps

Comment: @MilesFett I suggest adding the `application.screenupdating` bits from my post as well. It significantly speeds up runtime if excel doesn't have to show every step on-screen, especially when modifying a large amount of cells.